# Vector spaces and endomorphisms as $K[X]$-Modules

Tags: vector-spaces, modules

Given a $K$-vector space $V$ together with a $K$-linear endomorphism $\varphi$. $V$ gets a $K[X]$-module structure on $V$ via $fv:=f(\varphi)(v)$. I would like to show the associative law for the module, but I'm not quite sure how it works. It should be like the following:
Let $f,g\in K[X]$. Then $(fg)v=\sum_{ij} (a_i \varphi^i b_j \varphi^j)(v)=\sum_i a_i \varphi^i(\sum_j (b_j \varphi^j)(v))= f(\varphi(g(\varphi(v)))=f(gv)$.
Does this make any sense and how is the second equation justified?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The last equation should be $f(\phi)(g(\phi)(v)) = f\cdot (g\cdot v)$, the justification for your second equation is the distributive law  of composition over addition in $\text{End}_K(V)$ (i.e., $\alpha\circ (\beta + \gamma) = (\alpha \circ \beta) + (\alpha\circ\gamma)$).

Comment: Allright, thanks! So I don't need in this question that $\varphi$ is a $K$-linear endomorphism? But I would need this for  $f.(v+w)=f.v+f.w?

Comment: Yes, you do-the distributive law is the one in the ring of $K$-linear endomorphisms (that is what $\text{End}_K(V)$ is). I suggest you see how this plays out "long-hand" by choosing two simple polynomials, say $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ and $g(x) = x^2 + x + 1$.

Comment: Do I need it in $\star$? $(fg).v=(x^4+x^3+2x^2+x+1).v=(\varphi^4+\varphi^3+2\varphi^2+\varphi+\varphi+1)(v)\stackrel{\star}{=}((\varphi^2+1)(\varphi^2+ \varphi +1))(v)=(\varphi^2+1)((\varphi^2+\varphi+1)(v))=f(\varphi)(g(\varphi)(v))=f.(g.v)$.